# LineRenderer puts end cap vertices in the wrong direction

Tags: unity-game-engine, line, vertex

I have a LineRenderer that had its `numCapVertices` set to 16. When I set the width of the line to 1, the end cap shows up normally, but when I set it to certain numbers, the LineRenderer puts the end caps inside the line, making them invisible.
When I set the width to 1:

```
lineRenderer.widthCurve = AnimationCurve.Linear(0, 1, 1, 1);
```

The outcome looks normal:

[image]

[image]

But when I do:

```
lineRenderer.widthCurve = AnimationCurve.Linear(0, worldCornors[0].x - worldCornors[3].x, 1, worldCornors[0].x - worldCornors[3].x);
```

with `worldCorners` being the world corners of the circles, the end caps don't show up correctly:

[image]

[image]

From the wireframe, it shows that the end caps are placed in the opposite direction and end up inside the line.

How do I fix this issue?

Note: the points used to draw the curves are unchanged. I just changed the width. The images I uploaded show different curves because I have multiple LineRenderers, and all of them share the same width, so all of them break at once.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turned out that `worldCornors[0].x - worldCornors[3].x` was negative and that caused the end caps to glitch out.